# Error on Set-AzureSubscription - ForbiddenError: The server failed to authenticate the request.

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage

I get an error when trying to set the azure subscription using the Windows PowerShell.

```
Set-AzureSubscription  -SubscriptionName  $azureSubscriptionName -CurrentStorageAccount $service_name
```

Set-AzureSubscription : ForbiddenError: The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is
valid and is associated with this subscription.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AzureSubscription  -SubscriptionName  $azureSubscriptionName -CurrentStorage ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureSubscription], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.SetAzureSubscriptionCommand

I confirmed in the azure portal that the service I am giving as a parameter is in the subscription passed in $azureSubscriptionName.

Other fact is when I list Azure Subscriptions the CurrentStorageAccountName is empty.

[image: Get-AzureSubscription]

What is wrong on this command? How can I set the current storage account?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have a look at this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/goutham/2015/06/16/azure-powershell-forbiddenerror-the-server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request-verify-the-certificate-is-valid-and-is-associated-with-this-subscription/. 
Here is a snippet:

> the below command does the magic of clearing your azure profile which is existing.
>   **Clear-AzureProfile**. 
>   You can also consider **deleting** the content of the folder **C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Windows Azure Powershell**  manually. After which again run **Add-AzureAccount** to get the fresh/new one by entering your subscription details and  then execute any Azure PowerShell commands that you wish to run

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I tried it before adding this post and I did it again deleting the content of the Windows Auzure Powershell folder.

Comment: Please try to use ‘Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile’ then using "import-AzurePublishSettingsFile  'path to downloaded file'". User 'Remove-AzureSubscription' to remove unused subscription. Try again, hope this helps.